# Issue using UITextField with long string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

So currntly I have multiple UITextFields whose data is automatically inputted for the user when the app launches, mainly gets the location of the user and inputs them into the textfields.

Now, the issue is, when the textfields are filled, the textfields expand in width with respect to how much text is in the body of the UITextFields.

Heres a few pics of what really is going on, I'm also using nib files to create the layout, the left pic is of the application not getting an address inputted into the UITextfield from CLGeocoder coordinates, whereas the right view shows the UITextfield getting address string from the CLGeocoder.

[image: Before and After Photo]

I also notice that when I finish typing in a field, the fields EXPAND after I press return and the keyboard is dismissed.

[image: After typing in a LONG STRING]

I'm sure there is probably a setting in the nib file I uncheck or maybe I have to do this programatically? By instantiating the UITextfields programatically i mean.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: DAM IT!!! haha... I was :P

Answer (score 1):

As Rocky has already said, the problem is with auto-layout option of iOS 6.0. I also ran into this painful thing a while back. Turn off Auto-layout but now you will have to maintain two storyboards, one for iPhone 5 and there other for iPhone 4 and lower. Fun isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you still decide to use auto-layout, make sure there are no User Constraints on the UITextFields where the Width is set to "Greater Than or Equal". This will allow the control to expand based on the content. If there are, just delete them.